# Get latest AMI in case of stack CREATE and keep same AMI in case of stack UPDATE

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I would like to use the same CloudFormation template for existing stacks (UPDATE) and also for new stacks (CREATE).
I'm using the Public SSM parameter store to get the latest AMI:

```
Parameters:
  LatestAmiId:
    Type: 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
    Default: /aws/service/ami-windows-latest/Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Base

Resources:
  Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
    ImageId: !Ref LatestAmiId
```

The problem is: When a new AMI released I can't update the exinsting stack, because it will try to replace an EC2 resource, also I can't pass an AMI which is used into `LatestAmiId` parameter.

I'm looking for a solution for using the same AMI in the case of stack `UPDATE` and to get the latest one in the case of stack `CREATE`.

Comment: You can't do this without custom resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround the two `ImageId` parameters: `InstanceImageId`, `InstanceImageIdLatest` and one condition `HasInstanceImageId` can be used:

```
Parameters:
  InstanceImageId:
    Type : String
    Default: ''
  InstanceImageIdLatest:
    Type : 'AWS::SSM::Parameter::Value<AWS::EC2::Image::Id>'
    Default: /aws/service/ami-windows-latest/Windows_Server-2019-English-Full-Base
Conditions:
  HasInstanceImageId: !Not [!Equals [!Ref 'InstanceImageId', '']]
Resources:
  Instance:
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::Instance'
    Properties:
    ImageId: !If [ HasInstanceImageId, !Ref InstanceImageId, !Ref InstanceImageIdLatest]
```

In the case of stack `CREATE` the `InstanceImageId` parameter should be blank and Instance will use the `InstanceImageIdLatest` parameter witch resolving the latest `AMI`.

In the case of stack `UPDATE` the `InstanceImageId` parameter should have an `AMI` which is currently in use.